# Autotools - compiling but not distributing

Tags: autotools

i have a directory structure as

```
src
 \__lib_foo
 |   \__ foo.c foo.h
 \__ main
      \__ main.c main.h
```

the main is the main application and main.c uses some function defined in foo.c.
The requirement for me is "lib_foo must be compiled but not distributed"..how can i achieve this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The autotools provide a framework for distributing source code, not compiled products.  If that is your question, you can easily use an autotooled project to construct a binary package (rpm, deb, pkg, etc.) and distribute that.  On the other hand, if you are merely looking for a way to use foo.c to construct a convenience library that main is statically linked against during the build, then (assuming you are using automake) you want to do put this in Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS= main
noinst_LIBRARIES = libfoo.a
libfoo_a_SOURCES = foo.c
```

If you change the name of foo.c to libfoo.c, the third line is not needed.

--EDIT after the question was edited to display a non-flat directory structure--

If you do not have foo.c and main.c in the same directory, there is a bit more work involved.
In toplevel/Makefile.am:

```
# You must list lib_foo first
SUBDIRS = lib_foo main
```

in lib_foo/Makefile.am

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = libfoo.a
libfoo_a_SOURCES = foo.c
```

and in main/Makefile.am

```
bin_PROGRAMS = main
main_LDADD = ../lib_foo/libfoo.a
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiled programs are never distributed, but the source to compiled programs is of course generally distributed. (There would not be much point in a source distribution without source, would it.) There is also `nodist_*_SOURCES` (cf. chapter 14.2 Fine-grained Distribution Control in the automake manual). Also note that `BUILT_SOURCES` is nodist by default unless overriden, e.g.

```
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
nodist_foo_SOURCES = foo.c
BUILT_SOURCES = foo.c
```

but:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = foo.c
BUILT_SOURCES = foo.h
```